# Sorting binary string in colex order

Tags: ordering

Do you know where Can I find an algorithm to sort a set of binary strings in colex order?

Recall, that two k−element subsets A and B
of a set with strict linear ordering $<$ are said to be in co-lexicographical order (colex order) if, for the sequences, a and b of their elements sorted in ascending order, there exists index$ i$ such that $a_i < b_i$ and $(\forall_j )_j > i \Rightarrow a_j = b_j$.

Comment: Any algorithm at all?  Surely you can think of one.  Just use any standard comparison-based sorting algorithm, with a comparison operation that is as you defined.  That seems to trivially give such a sorting algorithm.  So what is your real question?  Can you specify your question more precisely?  Perhaps you could also tell us what approaches you have considered and why you have rejected them, and your thoughts on this problem.

Comment: Also, your question asks about sorting binary strings, but your definition of colex order is for subsets.  Did you have in mind a particular isomorphism between binary strings and subsets?  I suggest you specify it.